# confusion matrix using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

So I have been having trouble plotting a confusion matrix on my data. I am making an image classifier on pycharm with python 3.6. Below is my code, can anyone tell me if my code is working correctly? because I can see a confusion matrix on the outcome but I am not sure if what I did is correct.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/MRI"

CATEGORIES = ["yes", "no"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

        break
    break
print(img_array)
print(img_array.shape)

IMG_SIZE = 50

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass


create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)



pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=5, epochs=20, validation_split=0.1)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
pred = model.predict(X)
pred = np.round(pred)

conf = confusion_matrix(y, pred)

import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(conf, annot=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()

model.save('64x2-CNN.model')
```

Comment: Can you please share your Confusion matrix and tell why it could be wrong?

Comment: so ye i didnt have enough rep but i edited my post

Comment: Unable to see the numbers properly, so can you tell in the comments, the value's of `conf` variable, and total number of samples in your dataset.

Comment: yo sorry for the late reply i have 227 sample u have any code so to show conf variable? cause idk how to

Comment: plt.figure(figsize=(10,10));
    plt.tight_layout();
    ax=sn.heatmap(conf, annot=True);
    bottom, top = ax.get_ylim();
    ax.set_ylim(bottom + 0.5, top - 0.5);
    plt.ylabel('True Label');
    plt.xlabel('Predicated Label');

Comment: sorry for the late reply i was at the uni for a whole day soo yeeee i get error on sns and conf idk why